# Did the rules for removing my votes change?

Tags: support, voting

When I try to undo a vote, I find this:
[image]

If my memory serves me right, I can undo my votes. Does my memory serve me right?

Comment: If you feel strongly about this, you could either minimally edit the question yourself (if you have the reputation to do so), or ask the OP to do so in a comment, and then alter your vote after the edit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Editing yourself in order to reverse a vote is _usually_ wrong, IMO.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think that's very possible to ask OP to change his answer so I can down vote it.

Comment: Ave, of course. It would only be applicable if you suggested that you would remove your down-vote and/or swap it with an up-vote.

Comment: It's like a toilet with 3rd level codelock. And inside before you'll need to flush the water you need to make exercises inside a toilet of heavyweight fitness machine in such a way that the angle that's on the wall (with math expression of physics). ... to go toilet and flush the water... just in case of need. It's just a button after all. And if you went out of the toilet and released that not enough water was or just go again here but you should wait. And you want to toilet very hard again....

Comment: @Xsi Analogies are extremely difficult even for native speakers to do. I would recommend being more direct and using much more simple language if you are trying to make a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your memory is *partially* right.

You can retract your votes within five minutes (not 100% on the exact time here, but it's a relatively short window) of casting them. After that, you're committed to it unless the post is edited.

Comment: Why? What if you change your mind?

Comment: @bjb568 The short version is that it's in part to prevent abuse (downvoting a bunch of answers to make yours stand out better, then retracting those votes, for example) and in part to encourage thinking before voting.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'd take the first point.  But I don't think that it _encourages thinking before voting_.  Had that been true, you would not see upvotes within seconds of a post on an _obviously incorrect answer_.

Comment: @Anna So I just downvote and don't bother retracting it at all? Seems harmful.

Comment: @bjb568 You can retract your downvote if the post is edited and improved.

Comment: @devnull It's certainly not foolproof. :)

Comment: @Anna But we're talking about tactical downvoting. The post may never be improved (it may be fine), and if it is improved I probably won't know (5 minutes delay is long after me leaving the page). So I would use tactical downvoting, never retract it, and probably nobody will ever find out (anon voting).

Comment: @bjb568 The point here is "don't vote for the wrong reasons and think before you click". Unlimited vote retraction doesn't make the scenario you just described any better.

Comment: Actually, it does. I would undownvote out of sympathy after my answer is (maliciously) promoted to the top spot. And people don't think, so "making them think before voting" doesn't really work. Especially if they don't know about it.

Comment: "I would undownvote out of sympathy after my answer is (maliciously) promoted to the top spot." - wait, what? I think you severely overestimate how many people feel bad about their malicious behaviour.

Comment: Ok, fine. So it makes absolutely no difference to tactical voting. So the only difference it makes is it prevents unupvoting wrong answers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/724/discussion-between-bjb568-and-anna-lear)